# Can Solr be used to match a document against keywords without storing the document?

Tags: solr, search-engine, solrnet

I'm not entirely sure on the vocabulary, but what I'd like to do is send a document (or just a string really) and a bunch of keywords to a Solr server (using Solrnet), and have a return that tells me if the document is a match for the keywords or not, without having the document being stored or indexed to the server.

Is this possible, and if so, how do I do it?

If not, any suggestions of a better way? The idea is to check if a document is a match before storing it. Could it work to store it first with just a soft commit, and if it is not a match delete it again? How would this affect the index?

Answer (score 3):

**Index a document** - send it to Solr to be tokenized and analyzed and the **resulting strings** stored

**Store a document** - send it to Solr to be stored as-is, without any modifications

So if you want a document to be searchable you need to index it first.
If you want a document (fields) to be retrievable in its original form, you need to store a document.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Avoid duplicate documents? Can you expand a little bit on your case...

Comment: The idea was to avoid storing documents that are not of interest, but we have now  decided that "Hey, it's a search engine, it can handle it." and just store/index everything, and then find the things we are interested in afterwards. This has the added advantage that we can go back and search documents that were initially not of interest.

Comment: Right, disk space is cheap. Certainly better than slowing down the indexing process...

Comment: To complement: If you already have the document and a unique key to access it, then you don't need to store it again, just store the key.